# Easy way to work around slow Selenium Python startup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I have a program I want to run using selenium specifically that takes a series of actions on a password-protected website. Basically, I need to be able to input a unique link and password when I get it, which will take me to the main website which I have automated. The issue here is that Selenium takes very long to get to load a webpage when you start it up and time is very important in this application. Inputting the link and launching the browser to that link directly takes a long time. What I have tried doing is preloading the browser to a different website (ie, https://google.com) beforehand, and then waiting on user input for the link to the actual page. This process works a lot quicker, but I'm having trouble getting it to work inside a function and with multiprocessing. I am using multiprocessing to execute this on a wide scale with lots of instances. I am trying to start all of my functions the second a link is defined by me. I am on Windows 10, using Python 3.8.3, and using Chrome for my Selenium browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver

global link
link = input('Paste Link Here: ')

def instance_1():
     browser1 = webdriver.Chrome(*my webdriver file path*)
     browser1.get('https://google.com')

     #need something that waits here until the link variable is defined by me

     browser1.get(link)

     #the rest of the automation works fine from here
```

Ideally, the solution would be able to work with multiprocessing. The ideal flow would be something like this:
1. All selenium instances" (written as their own functions) start-up and preload to a website (this part works fine)
2. They wait until the link to go to is specified (this is where the issue is)
3. They then go to the link and execute the automation (this part works fine)

Tldr; basically anything that would allow me to let the program continue while waiting on the input would be nice.

Comment: 'Headless' Mode

Comment: That doesn't substantially reduce time. I used the time module and found that the process takes about 2.1 seconds, but the loading alone is 3.4 seconds. With headless, it drops to about 3.1 seconds of loading time, but all of that could be avoided if there was just a way to preload the window.